# How to create a custom color scheme for a custom file type in VIM

Tags: vim

I am regularly looking at log files that can be difficult to pick the pieces of information out visually.  I was wondering if there was a way I can create a custom color scheme in vim that would pick certain strings out and change their colors like in a typical color scheme for a code file.

For example, a line that contains the string "com.domain.package.class" to be one color.  A line that starts with "INFO" be a different color.  A string that is a GUID format "********-****-****-*******" be a different color, etc.?  This would apply to any file that has a .lg# extention.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

A colorscheme is a global set of colors applied to syntax elements in vim.

What you want to do is create custom syntax elements and link them to the colorscheme definitions.

Read `:help syntax`, and make browse some of the code in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax`